# If value exists, do this. undefined vs null?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, null, undefined

I want to render certain action upon button click.

**The condition is:
(If value exists in input field, then write 'value exists'. If value doesn't exists, then alert).**

I tried to replace undefined with null. 
I also try to replace operator === and ==.
None works! Please help.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<input id='typer' type='text'></input>
<button onclick='hey()'>click</button>

<p id='pw'></p>

<script>

var pw
pw = document.querySelector('#pw');

function hey() {
    if (document.getElementById('typer').value !== undefined) {
        pw.innerHTML = 'value exists';
    } else {
        alert('value does not exists');
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check for the empty string instead `""`

Comment: `.value` always returns a string, never `undefined` or `null`. If nothing has been entered, it will be an empty string.

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: ohh "" worked thanks. But is there any alternate way to fix it?

Comment: you can cast the value to boolean `(!!document.getElementById('typer').value)` this means if `""`, `null`, `undefined` or `0` (number) not the 0 as string its `false`

Comment: Or simply `if (document.getElementById('typer').value) {` since `''`, `null`, and `undefined` are all "falsy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null`, `undefined`, and an empty string (`""`) are all 'falsey' values in JavaScript; this means that if you pass them into the `!` operator, the result will be `true`. You can test this out in your console by running `!("")`, `!(null)`, or (for `undefined`) by defining `var x;` and then calling `!x`.

What's more, an `if` statement doesn't actually check if its condition is equal to `true`, it checks if the condition is 'truthy' (i.e. evaluates to `false` when passed through `!`).

Therefore, all you need to do is set the condition of the `if` statement to `document.getElementById('typer').value`, since as long as the value of the element isn't null, undefined, or an empty string (or false, which is also falsey), the condition is truthy.

Comment: "undefined is a little tougher" -> `var x; !x`

Comment: Good point! I didn't think of doing it that way. Editing the response.

Answer (score 1):

For `<input type="text">`, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) states that the type of its `.value` property is a `DOMString`.

> `DOMString` is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings, `DOMString` is mapped directly to a `String`.

This means that `.value` will never be `null` or `undefined`; with this knowledge, when you want to know whether a value is present, you can do two things:

1. Use `value.length` to determine if the string is empty
2. Use `value` or `!value` itself in an `if` statement to determine whether it's present or empty respectively (an empty string evaluates to `false`, whereas a nonempty string evaluates to `true`)